# How to load images from URL in App widget Android?

Tags: android, image, widget, viewflipper

I am making a widget similar to that of YouTube and default Weather/News one. I have a view flipper in which I add layouts dynamically (which contains an ImageView and a TextView) using:

```
remoteViews.addView(R.id.viewFlipper, itemViews);
```

The problem is that I need to load images from a URL in that layout. What is the best way to do this ?

I have a Lazy List loader but that does not work on RemoteViews and even after modification I think it is not  correct to update the widget for every image which might drain the battery too fast.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure entirely what you are referring to without a code sample, but the [Android Developer's](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.htm) website has some great information. Since you want to mimic the behavior of the YouTube app, you'll want to use a collection layout like `AdapterViewFlipper` or `StackView`. All of these require a `RemoteViewsService` and `RemoteViewsFactory`. Your best bet is to have a background `Service` running that will asynchronously download the images you want.

> I think it is not correct to update the widget for every image which
>   might drain the battery too fast

This depends entirely on *how often* you are updating your set of images. If the app refreshes its set every 12 hours, then I cannot imagine any significant battery drain assuming there are no memory leaks/ background tasks constantly running. If you are still concerned, you could create a `ContentProvider` that stores all of these images and then only after the entire set is downloaded to you tell *all Views in the collection* to update with the new content.